# Can trigger io add a contact to the native contact book?

Tags: trigger.io

I'm creating an application that maintains an internal contact list. I'd like export them to the native contact list. I'm using the trigger.io module contact, but this only offers reading the contatct list. Does anyone know how to do the opposite?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently it is not possible to add a contact to the address book using our contact module.

However, we are working on the contact module in our next sprint and are likely to add this functionality. I will update here again when that is done.